# Is routing key in rabbitmq case sensitive?

Tags: java, rabbitmq

I am trying to send rabbit mq message on a exchange - `exchange-X` to a message queue - `queque-X` with routing key -`mc`, its being received well on my local rabbit mq but on production rabbit mq the message does not appear. The exchange  and the queue is binded with the specified routing key. In the below message `isSent` is true always but actually message does not reach at the queue only on prod rabbitmq env. Is routing key `mc` case sensitive ?

```
public void sendMessageCenterNotification(Map<String, Object> headerMap,String correlationId,String message) {
    boolean isSent = false;
    try {           
        isSent = rabbitMQ.messageSender(message, headerMap, "mc", correlationId);           
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error(correlationId + " - Exception occured in sendMessageCenterNotification:", e);
    } finally {
        logger.info(correlationId
            + "-inside sendMessageCenterNotification message sending to message center was "+(isSent?"successfull":"failed")+", message:"
            + message);
    }
}
```

Comment: According to the [tutorial](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-four-java.html), fanout exchanges ignore the routing key completely...

Answer (score 2):

From [the documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/amqp-concepts.html#exchange-fanout):

> A fanout exchange routes messages to all of the queues that are bound
>   to it and **the routing key is ignored**.

You probably want a different type of exchange for what you are trying to accomplish.

As a side note, the protocol (0.9) reference does not appear to mention case sensitivity, but in the client implementations **routing keys are case-sensitive**.

Comment: thanks I got the real cause, actually the binded routing key is set in uppercase, on my windows enviroment even with routing key in lowercase, it works perfectly but on production which is in linux env, it fails to route with lowercase.

Comment: @sachinrai you are welcome. However, if your exchange was indeed fanout (and in the context you provide in the question) the routing key did not matter. There was probably some other culprit.